# project proposal: English translation of Deligne's "La conjecture de Weil : II"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

First of all, I hope this "question" is appropriate here. If not, please delete it.

I would like to propose a translation project of Deligne's "La conjecture de Weil : II" 52_137_0">http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1980_*52*_137_0 into English.

I've begun to translate the first 1,5 pages here: http://codepad.org/hML0LYe1 (LaTeX code)

We should assign in this thread page numbers to persons who translate them and in the end merge everything together.

If 20 people were willing to join, everyone only had to translate 6 pages.

Here is a homepage: http://www.kellertimo.de/index.html

Comment: I am not sure how many people would be willing to collaborate on a project with "unknown (google)".

Comment: I would participate in that (I'm a native english speaker fluent in french).

Comment: I had the same thought as Angelo. Perhaps it's better  for you 
to set up a separate web page somewhere else with contact info etc.

Comment: I have edited my name to my real name. If there are enough willing participants, I will set up a web page.

Comment: I do not think that such "questions" should be "asked" on MO. Vote to close. 

Comment: Here is a homepage: http://www.kellertimo.de/index.html  Anyone interested may contact me.

Comment: Indpendent of whether this is on MO  or not.  Do you (know whether you) have permission to make a translation (publically available)? 

Comment: I don't know it, but as Deligne's paper is online, why shouldn't be a translation be allowed?

Comment: @T.K. Perhaps this would be something to find out first then. (I am coming of a bit negative here I guess, let me add that I do not want to discourage you and this could be a good activty. But it also could be a shame if you and others put a lot of effort in it and then well it is more or less wasted due to some legal problem.)

Comment: Since the comment changed while I typed and add on: I am not an expert on this, but just that something is online (freely available) does not  imply that you can do with it whatever you want. 

Comment: Well, then how could I find out if this is allowed?

Comment: To Timo: you should email the publisher.

Comment: I assume you have the online version from numdam. Go to there http://www.numdam.org/ and check general conditions. It says for example "It is forbidden to modify any content available on the NUMDAM site." And how 'owns' the content. Contact them and ask permission. Possibly you  need in addition author's permission, but 'they' should know this.


Comment: OK, I've written them a E-mail.

Comment: Well, at least this discussion has had one good consequence, convincing an user to come out of anonymity.

Comment: While I'm all in favor of a translation project, I have to say, the translation thus far is pretty garbled.

Comment: While I agree generally with the sentiment, and that famous articles should be as widely available as possible, I don't think this is an MO question.

Comment: It seems to me easier, and less time consuming, to learn enough French to read Deligne's article than it would be to translate it well.